# How to put my materialize dropdown button to the right?

Tags: html, css, materialize, dropdown

For some reasons i can't put my dropdown button to the right edge of my page, here is my code :

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
      <ul id="dropdown" class="dropdown-content">
         <li><a href="#accueil">Accueil</a></li>
         <li><a href="#entreprise">Notre entreprise</a></li>
         <li><a href="#réalisations">Nos réalisations</a></li>
         <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <a class = "btn dropdown-button" href = "#" data-activates = "dropdown">Mail Box
         <i class = "mdi-navigation-arrow-drop-down right"></i></a>
   </div>
```

Here is what i have : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pWpRRz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the following `css`

```
.container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 5%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.btn{
  float: right;
}
```

You can also check the [Updated Codepen.](https://codepen.io/kravisingh/pen/JrMWGZ)